# Persian numbers in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, persian

I'm trying to add some persian text to my SQL Server 2005 database.

There is no problem with letters, but persian numbers (`۱،۲،۳،...`) are converted to `?`...

For example, if I add this text (`سلام ۱۲۳۴‍‍‍`) to database, there will be (`سلام ؟؟؟؟`) in database/

What should I do? (for example, which collation should I use?)

I'm using `Arabic_CI_AS` collation. in [this](http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/change-database-collation.aspx) list, Farsi (Persian) collation is `Arabic_CI_AS`
(SQL Server 2005 doesn't have `Persian` collation, but 2008 has!)

Note: I can't use newer versions of SQL Server...

Comment: Is using one of the unicode datatypes (NChar, NVarChar) an option?

Comment: I'm using `nvarchar` data type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you insert string literals, be sure to mark Unicode strings with N'', such as

```
select N'سلام ۱۲۳۴‍‍‍'
```

Next, make sure whether the question marks are only a display problem in SSMS:

```
declare @t nvarchar(50) = N'سلام ۱۲۳۴‍‍‍'
select unicode(substring( @t, 1, 1))
select unicode(substring( @t, 2, 2))
select unicode(substring( @t, 3, 3))
select unicode(substring( @t, 4, 4))
```

returns the Unicode values for each character:

```
1587
1604
1575
1605
```

I remember that SSMS 2005 had problems displaying certain Unicode ranges in the results window.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Arabic_CI_AI collation 
and Solve this problem 
I hope that help you..